# Possible marriage Options?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Are there any NPCs that you can marry, have as your housecarl, and have them as a follower?

I am looking for a great follower/companion.

Answer (score 7):

The [NPCs available to be married](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aMarriage#NPCs_available_to_be_married) section on the [Marriage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aMarriage) page at the Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages, has a complete list of who you can marry, along with whether or not they can be a follower.

Cross checking against the [Housecarl](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Housecarl) page, I see that every single housecarl can indeed be married, and all of them qualify as a follower.

Comment: Though I think Lydia and Iona are the only ones that could meet *all* of the specifications. Unless I'm forgetting some of the other housecarls.

Comment: All of the housecarls, it turns out, are marriable and can be a follower.

Comment: Oh. Ha! Turns out I didn't get over half of the housecarls. That would explain it.

Comment: There's simply too much content in this game (not that I'm complaining)! :-)

Comment: Note that there is a possible down-side to this, in Hearthfire. If you marry the Housecarl for the house you've settled your family into, that's one less capable defender you could have for your house. For ideal home defense, the following roles should be filled by separate and strong individuals: Spouse, Housecarl, Steward, Follower.